# Proving that a disconnected simple graph $G$ implies $|E| \leq \binom{|V| - 1}{2}$

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

This question is the contrapositive of Bondy and Murty's Graph Theory with Applications (1976):

> 1.6.5 (a) Show that if $G$ is simple and $\varepsilon > \binom{v - 1}{2}$, then $G$ is connected.

I'll just define $n$ to be $|V|$ and $m$ to be $|E|$. Also, the number of components of $G$ will be $\omega(G)$.

---

My draft is that, since $G$ is disconnected, then the components of $G$ must be at least two. Then, we'll consider $\sum_{i = 1}^{\omega(G)}m_i$ and it's relationship with $m$.

For $x, y\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $\binom{x}{2} + \binom{y}{2} < \binom{x + y}{2}$ so we'll try to check if $\binom{x}{2} + \binom{y}{2} \leq \binom{x + y - 1}{2}$. I'll skip this part, but it is true since, if both $x$ and $y$ are greater than $1$, then $\binom{x}{2} + \binom{y}{2} < \binom{x + y - 1}{2}$, and if either $x$ or $y$ is $1$, we have $\binom{x}{2} + \binom{y}{2} = \binom{x + y - 1}{2}$. Either way, $\binom{x}{2} + \binom{y}{2} \leq \binom{x + y - 1}{2}$.

If $G$ has only two components, then using the identity $\binom{x}{2} + \binom{y}{2} \leq \binom{x + y - 1}{2}$ is enough. And if $G$ has at least two components, we'll use $\binom{x}{2} + \binom{y}{2} < \binom{x + y}{2}$ until it boils down to only two terms satisfying $\binom{x}{2} + \binom{y}{2} \leq \binom{x + y - 1}{2}$.

Therefore, if $G$ is disconnected, then $|E| \leq \binom{|V| - 1}{2}$.

By contrapositive, if $|E| > \binom{|V| - 1}{2}$, then $G$ is connected.

---

Is this draft valid?

Comment: Looks fine to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks fine. However, you might want to be careful how you phrase the part if there are more than $2$ connected components. You cannot use words like "boil down to only two terms".

Here I'll just present another proof to your contrapositive that is pretty neat.

Suppose that $G$ is disconnected. Consider the average of the degrees of all the vertices. Let $E$ be the number of edges and $V$ be the number of vertices. Then, we have:

$$
\frac{1}{V}\sum_u\deg(u)=\frac{2}{V}E>\frac{2}{V}\binom{V-1}{2}=\frac{(V-1)(V-2)}{V}=V-3+\frac{2}{V}.
$$

Clearly, there must exist a vertice with a degree of $V-2$, which means if $G$ is disconnected, it must contain a connected component of size $V-1$ and an isolated node. However, then, there can be at most $\dbinom{V-1}{2}$ edges, contradicting $E>\dbinom{V-1}{2}$.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I haven't stated it. I'm not allowing myself to use $\deg(x)$ because I felt like it was cheating, and probably overkill.

The "boil down to only two terms" refers to $\binom{x}{2} + \binom{y}{2} < \binom{x + y}{2} \Rightarrow \binom{x}{2} + \binom{y}{2} + \binom{z}{2} < \binom{x + y + z}{2}$.

Comment: You should clarify this in an exam. Other than that, you solution is correct.